# Why does this PowerShell script hang?

Tags: powershell

Today I had to use `Start-Sleep` many times so I thought I would create a shortcut function for it, `sleep($time)`. However, whenever I entered the function it never exits! It must be an issue with either the data type for the argument for `Start-Sleep` or the way I am declaring the function. Instead of posting the whole script, I've posted this useless one that would make a familiar beep pattern if it worked:

```
function beep {
    Write-Host `a
}

function sleep {

    param([int]$time)

    Start-Sleep -m $time
}

beep
sleep(300)
beep
sleep(200)
beep
sleep(50)
beep
sleep(300)
beep
sleep(450)
beep
sleep(200)
beep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My system already has an alias for Start-Sleep called, oddly enough, `sleep`. run this to see if you have it `dir alias:sleep`.  Try a different name for your function to see if that helps.

Comment: I would just add that order of commands causes that alias sleep takes precedence before function sleep - thus you would eventually get your prompt back (after 300 secs in first run).

Comment: I never thought about the fact that `sleep` might already be defined. Nice catch